# Ruby on Rails: how to extract part of web-app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extract, subapplication

I have a big application and I need to extract part of this application to separate small application. I'm going to develop big application, but I want to small app to be up to date.

What should I use for this purpose?

P.S. I use Ruby on Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you could consider.

- [Rails Engines](http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/05/rails-3-plugins---part-2---writing-an-engine/)
- [Rack Middleware](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/26/the-rails-3-router-rack-it-up/)

The new router in Rails 3 offers some very powerful facilities for routing to rack applications embedded with the application